# I am trying to open a modal window with some effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `openModal()` function gets called on the click of a function.

I checked on Google that the transition property doesn't work with the display property in CSS. The other way round is to do it with opacity. But I am unable to call animation from JavaScript for CSS property.

```js
    var whm, whs, whd, whc;
function openModal(a) {
        whm="myModal"+a;
        whs="mySlides"+a;
        whd="demo"+a;
        whc="caption"+a;

  document.getElementById(whm).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(whm).style.opacity = "1";
 // document.getElementById(whm).classList.add('didLoad');
 //document.getElementById(whm).className += " didLoad";

  document.getElementById(whm).style.webkitTransition = "background 2s";
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
```

Whole code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.didLoad
{
 background-color: black;
 transition: background-color 2s;
 
 -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
  
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(1);currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(2);currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(3);currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal(4);currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x301" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x302" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x303" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides1">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x304" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption1"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1401" style="width:100%; height:100px;" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1402" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1403" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo1 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1404" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x201" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x202" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x203" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x204" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption2"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1301" style="width:100%; height:100px;" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="bhai">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1302" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="bhai bhai">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1303" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="bhai bhai bhai">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo2 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1304" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="fuck off">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides3">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides3">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides3">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides3">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption3"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo3 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%; height:100px;" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo3 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo3 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo3 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal4" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides4">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides4">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides4">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides4">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x300" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption3"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo4 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%; height:100px;" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo4 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo4 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo4 cursor" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1400" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
 var whm, whs, whd, whc;
function openModal(a) {
  whm="myModal"+a;
     whs="mySlides"+a;
  whd="demo"+a;
  whc="caption"+a;
  
  document.getElementById(whm).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(whm).style.opacity = "1";
 // document.getElementById(whm).classList.add('didLoad');
 //document.getElementById(whm).className += " didLoad";
 
  document.getElementById(whm).style.webkitTransition = "background 2s";

  

}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById(whm).style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName(whs);
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName(whd);
  var captionText = document.getElementById(whc);
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle??

Comment: If the element is not displayed, transitions won't work. When you set `display` to `block` and `opacity` to `1`, the element is drawn with that opacity. Transitions only work if the element is in the layout (regardless of its visibility) and if the initial value of the property you're trying to animate was explicitly set. Use `visibility` instead of `display`, if possible, or use JS, or there are other ugly workarounds.

Comment: @Gabriel visibility cannot work because it's a modal window and it covers the whole page. Once the display is set to block, after that the opacity value is changing.'

Comment: @mplungjan I cannot edit the question so, the whole code is in the answer section

Comment: You gotta learn about the JS loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop `display` and `opacity` are being set at the same time. The element starts with `opacity=1`, therefore there's nothing to animate. Your options are to use `visibility` and insert the dialog HTML with JS before it's displayed (instead of having it always there hidden). Or to trigger a reflow in the middle.

Comment: @mplungjan yeah I did

Comment: @Gabriel Tell me the workarounds please. I have edited the question with the whole code.
I have tried several workarounds like adding a newclass but in vain

Comment: Use only `opacity` instead of `display`. Remove the dialog from your page and create it in `openModal()` (and of course remove it after it's closed). Use a `setTimeout` with zero delay. And don't change the transition in your JS, that makes no sense.

Comment: What in it? @mplungjan

Comment: You code and my attempt to make it run does not work. Your slides array is empty

Comment: the slides do not exist until after openmodal.  But you try to run slides before they do. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Transitions don't work with `display` but with a new `class` and CSS animations, you can do some nice things (I only animated the 'show') :

```js
var show = document.getElementById('show');
var hide = document.getElementById('hide');

show.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('hello').classList.add("active");
});

hide.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('hello').classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#hello {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hello.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn .4s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="hello">
    <p>Hello world !</p>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  </div>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
```

Comment: does it apply on modal windows?

Comment: What do you mean ?